# Remove Duplicates from Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two strings like below and I need to remove the duplicates.

I.E., I need to remove/ignore the common elements in both the strings and show only the difference.

```
var char1 = "AAA-BBB|BBB-CCC|CCC-AAA";
var char2 = "AAA-BBB|BBB-CCC";
var removeDuplicates = //<-- Here I need CCC-AAA only
```

Here I have tried it,

```
 var Joined = char1 + "|" + char2;
 var removeDuplicates = $.unique(Joined.split('|')); //<-- Result : "AAA-BBB|BBB-CCC|CCC-AAA";
```

Comment: So, you need to remove duplicates from a list of strings after this string is split by the `|` char?

Comment: [From `$.unique()` docs](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/): *Sorts an array of DOM elements, in place, with the duplicates removed. Note that this only works on arrays of DOM elements, **not strings or numbers.***

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9229784/3569921

Comment: Yes.Lets say your string is A,B,B,C,D,D then i need my result is : A,C only

Comment: Oh, so if string has duplicates, remove all instances of that string.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885557/simplest-code-for-array-intersection-in-javascript for array intersection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery's `$.grep` can be used to remove all duplicates in an array

```js
var char1 = "AAA-BBB|BBB-CCC|CCC-AAA";
var char2 = "AAA-BBB|BBB-CCC";

var removeDuplicates = $.grep(char1.split('|'), (function(y) {
 return function(item) { return $.inArray(item, y) === -1 }
})(char2.split('|')));

console.log( removeDuplicates );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Op wants to remove duplicates, so there shouldn't be any AAA-BBB & BBB-CCC

Comment: i need Non-Duplicated value only : CCC-AAA only

Comment: @Eric Exactly yes

Comment: Suggested edit - don't use `char2.split('|')` inside your filter function - assign it to a var outside your function and use that pointer inside your function.

Comment: Heres a [JsBin](http://jsbin.com/sidanap/edit?js,console) where I've fiddled around with this idea and a bit more, maybe you'll find it useful in some way.

Comment: @Adam - Sure, splitting on every iteration is uneccessary, I can just bake that array in at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply make an array from the parameters and [Array#filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the array one returning only the elements that are not in the second array with [Array#indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```js
var char1 = "AAA-BBB|BBB-CCC|CCC-AAA",
    char2 = "AAA-BBB|BBB-CCC",
    removeDuplicates = function(str1, str2) {
      var arr1 = str1.split('|'),
          arr2 = str2.split('|');
      return arr1.filter(function(item) {
        return arr2.indexOf(item) === -1;
      });
    };

console.log(removeDuplicates(char1, char2));
```